# delete € symbol from span tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I have a span tag:

```
<span style="color:red" class="LevelPrice">Fachhandel&nbsp;Preis&nbsp;320,00 € (CHF)</span>
```

Is it possible to delete the € symbol via javascript or jquery on page load?

Comment: Isnt it an option to just not output it, server side?

Comment: Its crazy the store end defaults to € when you put CHF, ends up showing 370,40 € (CHF)

Comment: You should really find a server-side solution. What if a customer has JavaScript disabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.LevelPrice').text($('.LevelPrice').text().replace('€', ''));
});
```

You can use `replace(/€/g, '')` as well.

Comment: Would benefit (for minor efficiency and more significant readability) by storing `$('#LevelPrice')` in a variable).

Comment: Just a note about your jquery LevelPrice is not the id of the element.

Comment: *Don't micro-optimize.* The speed benefit is so small that you can't even measure it. Go with what's most readable and easiest to maintain.

Comment: The primary reason (as stated in my original comment) for the change is readability.

Comment: @Juhana: There's absolutely nothing wrong with making minor optimizations. They do add up. Nothing in the suggested optimization would compromise code clarity, and would instead improve it IMO.

Comment: am not i am is right, but I wrote it to be easier to understand (hopefully). And this is not the solution I recommend, as a lot depends on it working.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('span.LevelPrice').html(function(i, html) {
     return html.replace(/€/g, '');
});​
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/PYxkE/4/

Comment: This will only remove the first occurrence of the character http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/PYxkE/2/

Comment: @Curt — Since there isn't a second occurrence of the character, that isn't a problem.

Comment: @Curt Thanks, while it isn't a problem for the example text I've updated the answer to fix it.

Comment: Part of the point of passing a function is that you don't need to do `$(this).html()` to get the content. Just use the second parameter to the function. `function(i, html) { return html.replace(/€/g, ''); }` http://jsfiddle.net/PYxkE/4/

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks. That'll teach me to check the API in future!